# Android PreferenceScreen with table like entries

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

I wonder if there is a good practice to insert an array of numbers in preferences. something like this (Excel):

[image]

I am concerned about the design of the layout.

In excel it is a clear table layout to obtain those 8 values in a fast way, in the preferences it is not that clear.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are any "good practices", as the shared preferences, being a [key/value storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref), are not the most adequate for something like this. Having said that, I would care more about if it's spare data (few filled cells against total number of cells) or not. if it is, naming the keys as COL_ROW might save you a lot of space.

If the information is dense (most cells filled) I would use a SQLite Database (but I guess from your question that you would prefer not to).

Comment: thank you for the answer, but I am more concerned about the layout issue, rather than storage. I should have mentioned it in the question, I ll update it. It was not clear.